# LVM Unable to remove physical volume

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning, lvm, lvm2

Aim: To remove the physical volume from the LVM in order to reformat it.

LVM Setup:
1x 2TB HDD
1x 3TB HDD

Problem: When trying to pvmove, I get an error saying "No extents available for allocation" and when running pvdisplay I get the following:

> --- Physical volume ---
>   PV Name             /dev/sdb
>   VG Name            StorageArray
>   PV Size               2.73 TiB / not usable 3.46 MiB
>   Allocatable          yes (but full)
>   PE Size               4.00 MiB
>   Total PE              715396
>   Free PE              0
>   Allocated PE       715396
>   PV UUID             BemunR-U7S2-GoRU-5lTh-ESy2-sS8o-LpmXXr
>
> --- Physical volume ---
>   PV Name            /dev/sdc
>   VG Name            StorageArray
>   PV Size               1.82 TiB / not usable 1.09 MiB
>   Allocatable          yes (but full)
>   PE Size               4.00 MiB
>   Total PE               476932
>   Free PE               0
>   Allocated PE       476932
>   PV UUID              xNhWUT-VrEa-vdLP-c2Cg-mhcF-VHdT-bubG9E

However, none of the harddrives are full, current occupied space is 1.8TB, 2.2TB free.

I was thinking to run lvreduce -L2048TB, however it throws a warning about possibly loosing data.

Does anyone know how i can migrate data to the 2TB HDD, and then remove the 3TB from the LV.

Thanks.